# VBA Macro, get URL from given range loop and pull XML node

Tags: excel, xml, vba

I have this code that is set up to get data ZIP code (single node) from an XML URL. However, I actually have a list of URLs in Sheet1, Column B that I need to loop through until all the data is extracted.

I dont want to have to update the code each time individually per URL. There are thousands... How would i be able to do that?

Here's an example of a working code for a single URL:

```
Sub test1()
Dim xmlDocument As MSXML2.DOMDocument60

Dim URL As String
Dim node As Object
Set xmlDocument = New DOMDocument60


URL = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("b2").Value

'Open XML page
        Set xmlDocument = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
        xmlDocument.async = False
        xmlDocument.validateOnParse = False

xmlDocument.Load URL



Dim nodeId As IXMLDOMNode
Dim nodeId2 As IXMLDOMNode
Set nodeId = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("/ZipCodeLookupResponse/Address/Zip5")
Set nodeId2 = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("/ZipCodeLookupResponse/Address/Zip4")
If Not nodeId Is Nothing Then
    Sheets("fy2016").Range("e2").Value = nodeId.Text & " " & nodeId2.Text
Else
    Sheets("fy2016").Range("e2").Value = "'ZIP code' was not found."
End If
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your code works you want something like a For Loop over all the urls. Move your document outside of the loop and load it inside the loop. I use an array to store the urls read in from the sheet for faster handling. Your construct wasn't handling any errors on parse so I have commented out related lines.

**Not tested.**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test1()
    Dim xmlDocument As MSXML2.DOMDocument60, URLs(), i As Long
    Dim node As Object, nodeId As IXMLDOMNode, nodeId2 As IXMLDOMNode
    Set xmlDocument = New DOMDocument60

    URLs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B1000").Value

    Set xmlDocument = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    xmlDocument.async = False
    ' xmlDocument.validateOnParse = False

    For i = LBound(URLs, 1) To UBound(URLs, 1)
        xmlDocument.Load URLs(i, 1)
        Set nodeId = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("/ZipCodeLookupResponse/Address/Zip5")
        Set nodeId2 = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("/ZipCodeLookupResponse/Address/Zip4")
        If Not nodeId Is Nothing Then
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("fy2016").Cells(i + 1, "E").Value = nodeId.Text & " " & nodeId2.Text
        Else
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("fy2016").Cells(i + 1, "E").Value = "'ZIP code' was not found."
        End If
        Set nodeId = Nothing: Set nodeId2 = Nothing
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm getting an error along this line - "        Set nodeId = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("/ZipCodeLookupResponse/Address/Zip5")". Error details  - The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available

Comment: You may need to reintroduce the Async line - uncomment it from the above

Comment: Uncommenting the Async line worked! But the 255 Transpose Character Limit When Returning Array is triggering an error for some URLS with length >255 characters. Another alternative to the Application.Transpose option pls